# Codeigniter pagination and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, pagination

I have this in controller:

```
function index(){


    $this->show();

}

function show($start=0){
    $start = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if(trim($start)==''){
        $start = 0;
    }

    $this->load->model('post');
    $data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts(4,$start);

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url']=base_url().'posts/show/';
    $config['total_rows']=$this->post->get_posts_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="tsc_pagination tsc_paginationA tsc_paginationA01">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="current"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;';
    $config['last_link'] = '&gt;&gt;';


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['pages']=$this->pagination->create_links();


    $this->load->model('about_me');
    $data['about_me'] = $this->about_me->get_about_me();

    $this->load->model('sponsors');
    $data['sponsors'] = $this->sponsors->get_sponsors();


    $this->load->view('post_index',$data);
}
```

This in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|uploads|assets|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Somehow, when i click on pagination links images are broken. I think that the problem is in .htaccess file, but i can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Are you loading your images via relative urls?

Comment: when the url is: localhost/cms, 
<?php base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $posts[$i]->image;?> this works fine.

But when pagination links are clicked something goes wrong, and no images are displayed...

This is base_url:
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cms/';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your actual code for the image path is this:

```
<?php base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $posts[$i]->image;?>
```

Then that's your problem right there.  `<php base_url()?>` doesn't echo anything; your actual path will be `uploads/<?php echo $posts[$i]->image;?>`.

Just change the beginning to `<php echo base_url()?>` and you will be fine.

(If you don't already have it in there, you might need to add `http://` to the beginning of your base url.  Otherwise, it'll still look like a relative link.)